# position: sticky; ignoring z-index / Bootstrap 3 menu tucks underneath sticky elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, sticky

I have a list of items that are broken down categorically into a hierarchy. Each element has children, and each of these children has other children. They are displayed left to right, forming a tree that can span possibly multiple pages, and on the right most side are a list of final children. Each of the entities has a Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu. The entities are designed with position: sticky;, so that as you scroll down the page to view the longer list of it's children, it will scroll with you to keep the user aware of what the children's parents/grandparents are. Each div (Listing the type of data, name, status labels, etc has a "More" button that displays a Bootstrap 3 drop down menu. When the menu appears, the child next to or sibling below it (more sticky "entity" containers) appear over top of the Bootstrap drop down menu . z-index is being completely ignored. Can anyone shed some light on why this is occurring or if further detail is needed to provide assistance?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you add a fiddle to explain it well? The description makes it more complicated.

Comment: Hi Shafeeque. I put up a demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/james_7519/ydx8zs3c/1/ Click the "More" Bootstrap button under any Player and you will see what I'm referring to. Thanks for your help! :-)